# How to convert to using Promises and Q Library

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, q

We have an application that is growing and our client side scripting needs to be refactored to be cleaner, leaner, and more maintainable. I'm attempting to take a small module a utilize *Q* library for promise chaining.

As you can see I need to pass some return values back from the initial function to the rest of the promise chain.
Can someone please help me understand what I need to do to get the first function returning properly as a Promise? And then explain the chain?

Here is my starting point:

```
var promise = new Q.Promise(generateMoveRequest)
    .then(function (id) {
       var woNum = 12345;
       return layoutInit(woNum, id, true);
    }).then(function (result) {
        if (result) {
          return moveRequestInit(result, true);
        } else { 
          throw new Error('Template not loaded');
        }
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

**Generate Move Request:**

```
generateMoveRequest: function () {
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: window.contextPath + '/api/settings/getjson',
            data: {name: "the_name"},
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.length) {
                    var id = $.parseJSON(data).Parent;                                          
                    return id;
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("xhr: ", xhr);
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
```

**Layout Init:**

```
layoutInit: function (num, id, appendLayout) {
    $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: window.contextPath + '/some/url',
            data: {num: num, id: id},
            success: function (data) {
                return layoutInit.callback(data, appendLayout);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("xhr: ", xhr);
            }
        });
    },
    callback: function (data, appendLayout) {
        if (data && data.toString().toLowerCase() !== "blank") {
            if (appendLayout) {
                $(data).insertBefore($("#detailsection"));
            } else {
                $("#detailsection").html(data);
            }                               
        } else {
            $("#detailsection").html('');
        }
    },
```

The ***generateMoveRequest*** function will execute but the chain never proceeds any further. No .then() execution and ***layoutInit*** never gets called.

I'm using the Q Library but some of the examples seem to leave out how to start/create the promise or turn the initial function into a Promise.

Can someone explain what I have wrong here or provide me with a clean example?

Comment: Your function `generateMoveRequest` should return something: `$.ajax` returns a promise (it has a `then` method), so you can just return that.

Comment: @trincot i have it returning a value => id

Comment: That is the return value of the success callback, not of the function `generateMoveRequest`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery implementation of promises does not follow the A+ standard, so you're better off with Q.

The promise must receive a function with 2 parameters - `resolve` and `reject` - which are also functions (remember that Javascript is a functional language). The `resolve` function must be called on success and `reject` on error. Whatever you pass to those functions will be available in the `then()` and `catch()` callbacks.

Long story short, rewrite your code like this:

```
var generateMoveRequest = function (resolve, reject) {
  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: window.contextPath + '/api/settings/getjson',
    data: {name: "the_name"},
    success: function (data) {
      if (data.length) {
        var id = $.parseJSON(data).Parent;
        resolve(id);
      } else {
        reject({message: 'Data not received'})
      }
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      reject({message: errorThrown})
  }
  });
}

var promise = new Q.Promise(generateMoveRequest)
    .then(function (id) {
       var woNum = 12345;
       return layoutInit(woNum, id, true);
    }).then(function (result) {
        if (result) {
          return moveRequestInit(result, true);
        } else {
          throw new Error('Template not loaded');
        }
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error.message)
    });
```

Later edit - see snippet to understand how Promises work:

```
// any number of params
function willPerformAnAsyncOperationAndReturnAPromise(firstParam, secondParam, thirdParam) {
  var promise = new Q.Promise(function (resolve, reject) { // always resolve & reject
    // perform an async operation, like waiting one second
    window.setTimeout(function () {
      if (firstParam !== 0) {
        // if the 1st param is not 0, it's a success
        resolve ({
          first: firstParam,
          second: secondParam,
          third: thirdParam
        })
      } else {
        reject({message: 'The first param must not be null'})
      }
    }, 1000)
  })

  return promise
}

willPerformAnAsyncOperationAndReturnAPromise(1, 2, 3)
  .then(function (data) {
    console.log(data)
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error)
  })

willPerformAnAsyncOperationAndReturnAPromise(0, 2, 3)
  .then(function (data) {
    console.log(data)
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated! I now realize that any Promise function must have resolve and reject explicitly. Makes more sense now. Worked like a charm after that.

Comment: It works, but it uses the [`promise constructor antipattern`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it), since `$.ajax` is already a promise.

Comment: Do note that as of jQuery 3.0, jQuery's implementation of Promises is [A+ conformant](https://promisesaplus.com/implementations#inside-frameworks).

Comment: What if I have a function that is a promise but takes 2 arguments? Ex: generateMoveRequest(param1, param2). Does it need a wrapped to promise and chain?

Comment: @Encryption In your case, the `generateMoveRequest` is the async operation that you wrap in a promise and will always take 2 parameters. I've added an explanation in the original answer for your to better understand.
@trincot if the initial promise is not A+, it's not an antipattern. Better wrap it now in a compatible type as it will be easy to refactor later

Comment: @motanelu thank you for the edit with extra example.

Answer (score 0):

Some issues:

- Your function `generateMoveRequest` should return something: `$.ajax` returns a promise (it has a `then` method), so you can just return that;
- You don't need to create a new promise, as `generateMoveRequest` returns one. This way you avoid the [promise constructor anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it).

Suggested code:

```
generateMoveRequest: function () {
    return $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: window.contextPath + '/api/settings/getjson',
        data: {name: "the_name"},
    }).then(function (data) {
        if (data.length) {
            var id = $.parseJSON(data).Parent;                                          
            return id;
        }
    }).catch(function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("xhr: ", xhr);
        return null;
    })
}

var promise = generateMoveRequest()
    .then(function (id) {
        var woNum = 12345;
        return layoutInit(woNum, id, true);
    }).then(function (result) {
        if (result) {
           return moveRequestInit(result, true);
        } else { 
           throw new Error('Template not loaded');
        }
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: Could the downvoter leave a comment so I know what I missed?